# Deserialize XML to generated class by xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xml

I generated classes using `xsd.exe` and I got over 40 classes:

Link : https://www.pastiebin.com/5cc3253981ff6

And now I want to only deserialize adres
That's my deserializer:

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Adres));
 using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlDocumentText))
 {
     Adres info = (Adres)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
 }
```

But I got error `There is an error in XML document (1, 40)`

Below is only part of XML(the whole takes 15MB):

https://www.pastiebin.com/5cc325c457a55

Comment: Hi there - it would be much more helpful to allow people to help you if you put a minimal code example inline in your question explaining exactly what you've tried so far and where specifically you are encountering a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DomainClass.wpisyWpis));
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlDocumentText))
            {
                DomainClass.wpisyWpis info = (DomainClass.wpisyWpis)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
            }
```

You also need to add XmlRoot above this class :

```
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        [XmlRoot("wpis")]
        public partial class wpisyWpis
        {

            private Dokument dokumentField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://asseco.pl/xml/rpm/ksiegaPraktyka/2011/04/08/")]
            public Dokument Dokument
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.dokumentField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.dokumentField = value;
                }
            }
        }
```